# Filter out carriage returns in Excel using Applescript

Tags: excel, macos, odbc, export, applescript

I'm attempting to remove carriage returns from a few columns in an Excel file that is an export from a Filemaker database, the ultimate goal being to create SQL insert statements from the file.

I have found a few examples online for removing them in Excel, but I have not found Applescript equivalents that work. One suggestion was to use the clean function in Excel, CLEAN(text_with_returns). I guess I can create a new column in the table, create the clean version, and then delete the old column, but it seems there should be a more elegant solution?

I found this string in an Excel Applescript Guide PDF:

```
  replace (range "K:K" of worksheet "Sheet1") what "//r" replacement " " ¬
  search order by columns
```

I just have not found the correct form for the item to be replaced. Tried: "Char(10)", Chr(10), "//n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of these **AppleScript** constants (`return`, `linefeed`).

```
replace (range "K:K" of worksheet "Sheet1") what return replacement " " search order by columns -- this replace the Mac line breaks, equal Chr(13) in VBA

replace (range "K:K" of worksheet "Sheet1") what linefeed replacement " " search order by columns -- this replace the unix line breaks, equal Chr(10) in VBA
```

Answer (score 0):

While getting the hell away from FMP is always to be applauded, the way in which you're doing it sounds rather horrific. You wouldn't be trying to code munge data in your Excel spreadsheet into a gigantic SQL script? If so, that's just a ton of data corruption and other accidents waiting to happen.

The only task you should write an SQL script for is to create the database and its tables; the DB structure is fixed so safe and easy to hardcode. The right way to migrate your data into those tables would be to use ODBC calls to your new database, passing the original data as **[parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=odbc+parameters)** to your `INSERT` statements, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
cursor.execute("insert into products(id, name) values (?, ?)", productID, productName)
```

It's years since I've had to go anywhere near FMP so I can't advise on specifics, but it can [talk directly to other database systems via ODBC](http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/odbc.html), in which case you may be able to do the entire data transfer from within FMP itself, which'll be quicker and simpler than exporting your data to a dumb intermediate format and writing a script to chew through that.

Comment: Thanks Foo. I did not build the FM database, I'm only asked to report on it. I did look into the ODBC connection previously and I can't remember why I bailed on that. I'll revisit that option, as it would surely be preferable to this mess.